# How to add extra vertical space behind an equation in the equation environment in latex?

Tags: macros, equations, environments

I would like to make a new environment, that would add extra vertical spacing like this (to not have to write \vspace command over and over again):

```
\begin{equation}
some equation
\end{equation}

\vspace{3pt}
```

Comment: One can adjust \belowdisplayskip and \belowdisplayshortskip.  Not sure exactly when each is used.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `environ` package to achieve what you want.

---

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, environ, lipsum}

\NewEnviron{equationspace}{%
  \begin{equation}
    \BODY
  \end{equation}

  \vspace{2cm}
}

\begin{document}

{\LARGE Regular equation}

\begin{equation}
  \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i
\end{equation}

\lipsum[4]

{\LARGE Custom environment}

\begin{equationspace}  
  \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i^2
\end{equationspace}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My compliments..even if I didn't understood the reason for the user's request to have so much space.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, me neither. However the `2cm` were only used to better visualize the effect.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, this doesn't work for me...it adds space, that is true, but only after adding one more line which is already too much for me. I need just a little space.

Comment: If you try add just a 3pt or something like that it makes the vspace much bigger

Comment: @Helen001 Welcome to the users of TeX.SE. Please, can you edit your question and can you add a complete code with all the packages? Thus we know your mistakes. Thank you very much.